# Debugging low memory crash (threads related?)

Tags: android, crash

I'm trying to debug a mysterious crash of my Android application that seems to occur in the low memory conditions. The sources of the app in question are available from https://bitbucket.org/stativ/chmupocasi. The application's package is `cz.jirkovsky.lukas.chmupocasi`

What happens is that when the phone starts to run low on memory and I try to reopen the application from the list of recent apps (the one that shows after a long press of the *Home* button), the application crashes.

I've tried to debug the application using the Android Studio, but the application always crashes before hitting any of the breakpoints in the main Activity's onCreate() and onStart() making it impossible to debug. What is worse that even the logcat doesn't contain any information, the only related line shown when the app crashes is:

```
I/ActivityManager(  428): Displayed cz.jirkovsky.lukas.chmupocasi/.MainActivity: +1s45ms (total +23m23s835ms)
```

The full logcat is available at http://pastebin.com/TtSuqxCW, in case I'm missing something.

Finally, I've tried attaching the debugger to the application after it crashes, when the Android's dialog "Unfortunately the application has stopped" is shown. I don't see any of my code being run in any thread. Here is what the "Export Threads" contain:

```
<1> main@830017304224, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:-1)
  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:3147)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:76)
  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java:-1)

<10> Binder_2@830026133152, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java:-1)

<9> Binder_1@830026131496, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java:-1)

<8> FinalizerWatchdogDaemon@830026116408 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status: 'WAIT'
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:214)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

<7> FinalizerDaemon@830026115976 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status: 'WAIT'
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:169)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

<6> ReferenceQueueDaemon@830026115560 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status: 'WAIT'
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:129)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

<5> Compiler@830026115320 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status: 'WAIT'
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java:-1)

<3> Signal Catcher@830026114840 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status: 'WAIT'
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java:-1)

<2> GC@830026114616 daemon, prio=5, in group 'system', status: 'WAIT'
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java:-1)
```

If I try to examine the main thread, I can see that there is an unhandled exception somewhere in the ThreadGroup:

```
 No such instance field: 'nthreads'
```

Any ideas how to debug such crash or how to get more information about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a solution. It was actually two separate problems.

The first one was that my device (Huawei Y300) didn't log any stack trace that could be retrieved using logcat. This was likely resolved by a reboot that i did earlier today, or, less likely, by the fact that I tried to use logging via `android.util.Log` to log some debug info.

The second one was the crash itself. After getting the stack trace from the crash, the problem was quite easy to fix. Even though the previous information I obtained using debugger pointed to some problem with threads, the real cause was the following exception:

```
android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment cz.jirkovsky.lukas.chmupocasi.RetainFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

The true cause was that the `RetainFragment` was package private. However, *all classes inheriting from `Fragment` have to be public classes or public static inner classes*.

If they are not, it may bite you badly. The reason is that even though it seems to work fine when the class is package private, it will fail when a `Fragment` is being recreated after it was destroyed to reclaim some memory in a low mem condition.

The moral at the end is that you shouldn't always listen to what your IDE says, because I introduced the bug after the Android Studio told me that this fragment class can be made package private.